# C# WinForms: square background image not shown as square with BackgroundImageLayout.Zoom

Tags: c#, winforms, button, background-image, aspect-ratio

I have added a background image to 2 buttons.
The buttons are both rectangular: `button1.Size = 50 x 100`, `button2.Size = 100 x 50`.
The `BackgroundImageLayout` on both buttons is `Zoom`.

The image is 256x256 pixels large, the image background is transparent, the "plus" symbol is 252x252 pixels (=> a 2 pixels wide transparent frame around the "plus").

Based on the square image, I expect the size of the "plus" on both buttons to be about 44 x 44. Maybe a litte larger or smaller, but with square aspect ratio, because that's the purpose of `BackgroundImageLayout = Zoom`.

The following screenshot shows that the aspect ratio is not preserved:
[image]
The size of the "plus" on the left button is 41 x 49. On the right button, it's 49 x 41.

1. Why?
2. How can I get my expected square aspect ratio?

*EDIT*
I found that the aspect ratio is almost correct if I choose `FlatStyle = Popup`: The "plus" size is 49 x 48, maybe even 49 x 49 and 1px might be hidden behind the button frame. But then, there is no frame around the icon and the "plus" touches the button frame:
[image]
With `FlatStyle = Standard`, there is a nice frame (see first image), but this frame seems to squeeze the background image vertically. The width is obviously not adjusted.

Any workaround for that?
If possible, without overriding OnPaint() again.
And I don't want to increase the frame in the images.

Comment: What is the button.ClientSize? Square?

Comment: @TaW: same as the button.Size: 100x50 or 50x100, independent from the `FlatStyle`. `Padding` is 0, `Margin` also, but that's not relevant.

Comment: I can't reproduce this effect here. Is your app dpi-aware?

Comment: @TaW: My screen is 1920x1080, 100% (*not* 125% or 150%!). `AutoScaleMode=None`. VS 2019, .Net Framework 4.8. Plain simple WinForms test app with 2 buttons, nothing special.

Comment: It is fault of [ButtonStandardAdapter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonStandardAdapter.cs,84) + [ControlPaint.DrawBackgroudImage](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ControlPaint.cs,493).

Comment: Paint the Image yourself, without relying on the standard implementation, which is intended to produce a standard result, which may *conflict* with your intentions. Since you want a *custom* behavior, do implement one.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Thanks. This means there will be not easy workaround.

Comment: @Jimi: In my opinion, this is no custom behaviour, but a bug. But since the bug exists and causes a behaviour that indeed conflicts with my intentions, I have 2 options: a) stick with the current buggy behaviour. b) Implement the custom, intended, *correct* behaviour. I will go with a) for now, because the appearance is somewhat acceptable and we plan to migrate to WPF soon.

Comment: This *general purpose* handler is meant to work with Themed rendering and layouts across different Systems, using a common paradigm, which may not appear to be *sensible* everywhere, possibly. The clipping region is not the same everywhere. The result may look *buggy* (the rounding to preserve the image ratio could be more *efficient*). But, as mentioned, it has to take into consideration a lot of factors (plus a couple of real bugs that can make the Theme-generated clipping bounds of the Control  *uncertain*). Painting the Image solves it easily. But, since you're moving to WPF...

Comment: Has anybody confirmed the effect? I don't believe it is a bug in winforms but in the application. The links don't tell me anything..